# How to normalize result of sql query and how to refer a foreign key to two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the following tables:

`person` table

```
 +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | person_id | int(100)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | name      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

    +-----------+---------------+
    | person_id | name          |
    +-----------+---------------+
    |         1 | linon jacob   |
    |         2 | andrew simons |
    |         3 | john random   |
    |         4 | kayne ran     |
    +-----------+---------------+


EDIT:

As per the below comment:

    create table person(person_id int(100) primary key not null, name varchar(50) not null);
    create table questions(QID int(50) primary key not null, questions varchar(100));
    create table custom_questions(CID int(20) not null, questions varchar(50) not null, PID int(20), primary key (CID), foreign key (PID) references person(person_id));
    create table feedback_system(surveyID int(20) not null, recepient varchar(50), questionID int(20) not null, submitter name varchar(50), response varchar(10), primary key (surveyID, questionID));
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry Updated my question.

Comment: Regarding the question about the multiple choice foreign key, you can't.  I suggest justifying the need for 2 questions tables instead of 1.

Comment: @DanBracuk The questions table has standard set questions for an organization, however the custom questions table has questions specifically created by a person (hence, it has a PID), which he can ask his reviewers to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use some LEFT JOINs, as for each feedback line you EITHER have a question in `questions` OR you have a question in `custom_questions`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(q.questions, cq.questions) as 'question',
   f.recepient_name, 
   f.submitter_name,
   f.response
FROM feedback_system f
LEFT JOIN custom_questions cq
    ON cq.CID = f.questionID    
LEFT JOIN questions q
    ON q.QID = f.questionID 
WHERE f.surveyID = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I need to add some foreign key constraint in the feedback_system table on questionID?

Comment: @Ashwath - you don't need to add a key for this to work, but if you index `f.questionID`, `cq.CID` and `q.QID`, it will run faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your query. One is that you are in fact doing a cross join between `questions`and `custom_questions` resulting in a duplication of rows. The other problem is that the filtering on `survey_ID` is only done for custom questions, as `and` has higher precedence than `or`.

One way to write the query is to use `UNION ALL` to combine results from the two questions tables:

```
SELECT q.questions, feedback_system.recepient_name, feedback_system.submitter_name
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN feedback_system
ON q.QID = feedback_system.questionID
WHERE surveyID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT cq.questions, feedback_system.recepient_name, feedback_system.submitter_name
FROM custom_questions cq
INNER JOIN feedback_system
ON cq.CID = feedback_system.questionID
WHERE surveyID = 1
```

Another possibility would be to put all questions in a single table 'questions', with additional information for custom questions in a separate table 'custom_question_info'.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks. Do I need to add some foreign key constraint in the feedback_system table on questionID?

Comment: You do not _need_ to, (and as long as your are referencing two different tables, you can't either). However, specifying foreign keys where possible may improve query efficiency and data integrity.